# jCarousel Lite Installation issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, firebug, jcarousel

I'm have slight difficulty installing jCarousel onto my site.

http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/

I've made attempts to install this plugin however when /i render the installation through firebug, I get an error message:

> "$ not defined", $(".carousel").jCarouselLite({

http://natesmithen.com/wired/test/test.html

Does anyone know how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: Load this file before you use "$". http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: in my function.js file??

Comment: yes, either you can load in your my function.js or you can load in your html file before you use carousel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML File :
Load jquery file here

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Load carousel file after that

```
<script src="jcarousellite.js"></script>
```

Then do

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".carousel").jCarouselLite({
        //add properties here 
       });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: @Nate_tyrone:  Just an FYI, Zoli correctly answered your question 5 minutes before Aby.  Maybe his answer should be accepted instead, unless there's something more helpful about this answer.

Comment: Aby answer was slightly more understandable, thank you all for your help though much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

First of all start with add JQuery to your project. Maybe you will more problems with it because this is your first time. Don't worry!

1.Download jQuery library and add it.

-Download here: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery
 -Add to page header:

```
<head>
    <script src="/javascripts/1.7.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

2.Or add CDN Hosted jQuery file to your page header:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Right, I've done that which is visible on my domain, yet i'm still having the same problem?